# Simplifying, using logarithmic laws

Tags: logarithms

I'm just going through some simplifying questions in my textbook. It asks me to simplify a series of expressions. I'm fine with the logs and lgs, but I'm struggling on this one:

Simplify $$2\ln8 - \ln5 +2\ln10 $$

It asks me to state the logarithmic law I'm using, but obviously there are two.

Could anyone be so kind as to shed some light on the solving process for this question?

Thank you so much

Comment: Were u able to simplify the expression

Comment: It's $6\ln 2-\ln5+2(\ln2+\ln5)=8\ln2+\ln5=\ln256+\ln5=\ln{(256\times5)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use:**

1) $$k\ln a=\ln a^k$$

2) $$\ln a + \ln b = \ln ab$$

3) $$\ln a - \ln b = \ln \frac ab$$

Then $$2\ln8 - \ln5 +2\ln10 =\ln8^2-\ln5+\ln10^2=\ln\frac{8^2\cdot10^2}{5}=\ln 1280$$

Answer (score 2):

Using that
$$a\ln{b} = \ln{b^a}$$
$$\ln{a} + \ln{b} = \ln{ab}$$
$$\ln{a} - \ln{b} = \ln{a/b}$$
We can simplify

$2\ln{8}-\ln{5}+2\ln{10} = \ln{8^2}+\ln{10^2} - \ln{5} = \ln{\frac{64*100}{5}} = \ln{1280}$

Comment: Use `\ln` to make a logarithm symbol $\ln$, `ln` with no backslash looks like 'ell times en': $ln$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the law $$\ln(ab)=\ln a+\ln b$$ then we can simplify
$$2\ln 8-\ln 5 + 2\ln 10 = 2 \ln(2\cdot 2 \cdot 2) - \ln 5 + 2\ln (5\cdot 2)$$
$$= 2(\ln 2+\ln 2+ \ln 2) - \ln 5 + 2(\ln 5+ \ln 2) = \ln 5+8\ln 2$$
Now we could also simplify this to $\ln 5+\ln 2^{8}= \ln ({5\cdot 2^{8}})$, depending on what you want as an answer, but I think $\ln 5+8\ln 2$ looks nice enough, and we reach it by using only one logarithm law.